# Why does only SpaceX release every stage of rocket launch for the public viewing?

Tags: spacex, nasa, isro

What I mean is SpaceX telecast every stage of rocket launch.

But in NASA and ISRO, they just telecast rocket ignition launch.

ISRO and NASA never does this thing why so?

Comment: An easy guess would be that they hope to get more PR from it, NASA/ISRO/ESA/... are government-funded so possibly they don't see the need?

Comment: Is your question "why others (ULA, Orbital, etc) don't release launch videos on their own websites"? Actually they make online translations, too, so you can find the videos - if not on the sites than on Youtube.

Comment: @Muze I added details.

Comment: @peterh I'm still getting the hang of not getting suspended. after 2 years i'm am still a beginner.

Comment: @MatthewBenji please explore all the SE sites you will find interesting. . Good question!

Comment: @Muze Do the school well and go into a science direction. Astronomy and Space are friendlier a little bit.

Comment: @peterh yes i agree they are

Comment: This question needs supporting evidence. For the NASA launches I've seen, coverage was at least as comprehensive as that provided by SpaceX.

Answer (score 4):

Largely because SpaceX has had to prove itself as an independent contractor and as a company. [This article from 2011 was typical of the then-unproved SpaceX launch systems](https://www.forbes.com/sites/beltway/2011/05/31/the-case-against-spacex-part-ii/#6a993b266270)

> My main concern in raising these issues was that NASA not become overly dependent on an unproven launch provider -- one that only achieved its first launch success 32 months ago, but now says it will soon be ready to loft U.S. astronauts into orbit.

And here, it compares SpaceX to United Launch Alliance(ULA), which had far fewer launch failures under its belt

> Musk's enthusiasm is infectious and inspiring, but SpaceX's performance to date doesn't measure up to the rhetoric. SpaceX has only mounted seven launches since its inception, three of which were catastrophic failures. By way of comparison. Lockheed Martin's family of Atlas boosters has seen 97 consecutive launches without a single failure. The United Launch Alliance in which traditional providers Lockheed Martin and Boeing are partnered to offer both Atlas and Delta launch vehicles has had 50 successful launches in a row.

Showing live launches helped head off criticism that

1. NASA was wasting its time and money on a private company with no launch history
2. SpaceX was not able to deliver on its promises (i.e. solid launches and stage 1 recovery)

By contrast, neither Lockheed Martin, nor Boeing, (the two jointly own ULA) are wholly reliant on rocket launches to sustain their companies. They have long-term commitments to launch rockets as well. As such, NASA doesn't have much reason to focus on live launches.

ISRO is government funded. It doesn't have to prove itself to continue funding (it's a national interest that they build a successful rocket program), which might explain why [they have had more failures of late](https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/09/with-indian-rocket-launch-failure-2017-seeing-a-higher-accident-rate/). India shows no signs of letting that slow down their entry into the launch vehicle market.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it has much to do with convincing NASA or other potential clients at all. After all they are going to get more information directly from SpaceX than you can get from watching a video of the launch and will know how a launch went even without the video stream of the launch.

No I think it has more to do with Musk's personality in general and their ultimate goal of getting to Mars. Getting a colony going on Mars requires a couple things. A way to get there and enough people who want to and can afford to go. SpaceX is trying to build a way to get there and make it cheap enough that people can actually afford it so if they accomplish both those then you just need people who want to go. Getting people excited about space now will help with having people who want to go in 5/10/15/20 years or whenever they actually get BFR going to Mars.

I'm sure some people would say Musk is a glory hound or loves the lime light but I don't think that's actually the case. I think he's simply a true believer in what he is doing and enthusiastic so wants to share his excitement. I know it has rekindled my excitement about space and has gotten my son excited about it. He built his own FH out of legos after watching the launch but he was a little disappointed it didn't have a RUD.

Comment: Speaking to this, I'd entirely believe it was his intent to inspire by televising these things-- especially with his payload choice of a Telsa roadster. But I believe this answer and the other answer merged to be more accurate. He saw both the benefit in inspiration alongside the benefit of exposure, which is a win-win.